# Conversion of string and format

Tags: ocaml, pretty-print, printf

I have a piece of code as follows:

```
let pp_e (chan: out_channel) (e: e) =
  ...

(* ternary operator *)
let tern (b: bool) v0 v1 =
  if b then v0 else v1

let pp_x (chan: out_channel) (b: bool) (x: x) =
  let e0, e1 = ... in
  Printf.fprintf chan (tern b "(%a, %a)" "%a%a") pp_e e0 pp_e e1

Error: This expression has type string but an expression was expected of type
     ('a -> 'b -> 'c -> 'd -> 'e, out_channel, unit) format =
       ('a -> 'b -> 'c -> 'd -> 'e, out_channel, unit, unit, unit, unit)
       format6
```

`pp_x` does not compile, becase it doesn't consider `"(%a, %a)"` and `"%a%a"` as a format anymore. I still would like to use a ternary function, instead of `if...then...else...` to make the code more succinct. Does anyone know how to amend the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following should work:

```
let pp_x (chan: out_channel) (b: bool) (x: x) =
    let fmt0 = format_of_string "(%a, %a)" in
    let fmt1 = format_of_string "%a%a" in
    let e0, e1 = ... in
    Printf.fprintf chan (tern b fmt0 fmt1) pp_e e0 ppe e1
```

I've tested the basic idea and it worked for me. I can't test with your code because of the many parts that are missing.